# Progress bar not showing fill (vb.net/Visual Studio)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a code set up that will loop around and perform some network firmware functions. For the user, I have a progress bar form that pops up and shows them the status as it happens. The code is pretty straight forward:

```
 ProgressBar.Show()

 For j As Integer = 0 To datagridview.Rows.Count - 1

 'do network functions

 ProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Increment(100 / (datagridview.Rows.Count))

 next

 ProgressBar.Close()
```

ProgressBar is the name of the form with the progressbar on top of it. It's a very simple form. 
So if I put a break point at the "for" line, i.e. j = 0, I get my progress bar looking like this: 
[image]

Well, that gives no info. If I step to the point of the incrementing line below, it shows!
[image]

I thought that if I add some progressbar increment earlier, that the bar would fill. So I tried that. So here's what I changed it to:

```
 ProgressBar.Show()

 ProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Increment(100 / (datagridview.Rows.Count+1))

 For j As Integer = 0 To datagridview.Rows.Count - 1

 'do network functions

 ProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Increment(100 / (datagridview.Rows.Count+1))

 next


ProgressBar.Close()
```

Yet if I stop at the for loop in a break point, I still have a white bar instead of a green filled one. What am I doing wrong? I feel that this is something simple/noob level. Appreciated.

Comment: You are hanging the UI thread, forcing it to work on some kind of long running task.  So it doesn't get around to its normal duties, like responding to user input and painting the UI.  The white bar is actually the *unpainted* appearance of the window.  Calling  Increment() gets it slightly un-wedged, that also forces an Update() call which forces a paint.  After which it goes catatonic again, you won't see the traveling highlight note.  Instead, perform the "network functions" on a Task or BackgroundWorker.  Or use Async/Await if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Hans Passant's comment is correct.  Your UI thread is stuck.  It is waiting for your background thread (ie, your looping code) to finish before it repaints the screen.
When I use a progress bar, I put a DoEvents() call in the loop, like this:

```
ProgressBar.Show()

ProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Increment(100 / (datagridview.Rows.Count+1))

For j As Integer = 0 To datagridview.Rows.Count - 1
   'do network functions
   ProgressBar.ProgressBar1.Increment(100 / (datagridview.Rows.Count+1))
   'force .NET to update the forground thread, so the progress bar looks like it should
   Application.DoEvents()
Next

ProgressBar.Close()
```

The call to DoEvents, essentially halts the background execution until the UI has time to update, and then continues the background execution.

Comment: Thanks guys. I followed the advice and used a background worker. Works great.